# Angular 1.x templateCache put content from separate file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the Angular templateCache like in the example of Angular.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the
 template');
});
```

But I want to load my content from a local html file. The only solution what I've found is, to build the templateCache with grunt. That loads a html file and put the content into the second parameter of the `put` function.

Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't read local files via angular, you can make `$http.get()` request to web server to receive your file. Or using templates in build tools, like you already mentioned.